# How to subtract pandas series from pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

From a DataFrame `second_df`

```
import pandas as pd

second_df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]], columns=['a', 'c'])
second_df

    a   c
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   3   3
```

I build a series `second_s`.

```
second_s = second_df.iloc[0]
second_s

a    1
c    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

When I subtract this series from the DataFrame `first_df`

```
first_df = pd.DataFrame([[0.0, 0.1], [1.0, 1.1], [2.0, 2.1]], columns=['a', 'b'])
first_df

    a       b
0   0.0     0.1
1   1.0     1.1
2   2.0     2.1
```

I get

```
first_df.sub(second_s)

    a       b       c
0   -1.0    NaN     NaN
1   0.0     NaN     NaN
2   1.0     NaN     NaN
```

but I want

```
    a       b       c
0   -1.0    0.1     -1.0
1   0.0     1.1     -1.0
2   1.0     2.1     -1.0
```

The column "identifiers" `a`, `b` and `c` are not known prior to processing. There are a lot more columns in addition to `a`, `b` and `c` which are also not known before processing but the info about their existence known from their occurance in the dataframe only. How do I get what I need?

Comment: how are you getting -1,-1,-1 in column c? it does not seem to make sense

Comment: I think he wants c column to be 0. And then do the subtraction.

Comment: @AnkurSinha Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is use [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) for adding missing values, then add missing values to `Series` by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with new columns names, so possible subtract:

```
second_df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]], columns=['a', 'c'])

first_df = pd.DataFrame([[0.0, 0.1], [1.0, 1.1], [2.0, 2.1]], columns=['a', 'b'])

second_s = second_df.iloc[0]

df = first_df.reindex(columns=first_df.columns.union(second_df.columns), fill_value=0)
print (df)
     a    b  c
0  0.0  0.1  0
1  1.0  1.1  0
2  2.0  2.1  0

out = df.sub(second_s.reindex(df.columns, fill_value=0))
print (out)
     a    b  c
0 -1.0  0.1 -1
1  0.0  1.1 -1
2  1.0  2.1 -1
```

Comment: Thx. How expensive is this approach w.r.t. memory consumption and processing time?

Comment: @thinwybk - It depends of data, what is number of columns, rows?

Comment: I use this preprocessing in the context of machine learning model training. Means the rows can easily get into the range between 1000-10000. W.r.t. # of columns (features) it's either in the range between 5-10 or in the range of 1000-10000.

Comment: Expected output for the `c` row is `-1, -1, -1` (not `0.0, 1.0, 2.0`).

Comment: @thinwybk - How is count `[-1,-1,-1]` ?

Comment: `second_s` (series) shall be subtracted from `first_df` (dataframe) "row-wise".

Comment: @thinwybk - in pandas are aligned indices, so need index of Series a for subtract columns of a, index of b for subtract column b and similar for c.

Comment: @thinwybk - `"row-wise".` - sorry, but not understand.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC I think I have what you need:

```
second_df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]], columns=['a', 'c'])
second_df.iloc[0]
first_df = pd.DataFrame([[0.0, 0.1], [1.0, 1.1], [2.0, 2.1]], columns=['a', 'b'])
```

First, find the "new" columns that need to be appended to `first_df`. Then just select the columns that were present in `second_df` and apply the operation you had originally suggested.

```
new_cols = list(set(second_df.columns) - set(first_df.columns))
first_df = first_df.reindex(columns=[*first_df.columns.tolist(), *new_cols], fill_value=0)
first_df[second_df.columns] = first_df[second_df.columns].sub(second_s)
```

Then you will have

```
first_df
     a    b    c
0   -1.0 0.1  -1
1   0.0  1.1  -1
2   1.0  2.1  -1
```